# После изменения версии Gradle приложение не запускается на устройстве

Tags: gradle

После того как в ручную изменил настройки:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        -classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0'
        +classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
 -distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip
 +distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

при запуске приложение выдает Waiting for device. и название девайса.
Перезагружался, пробовал стандартный adm, genymotion, смартфон samsung.
Везде одно и то же Waiting for device.

Comment: Задача gradle собирать проект. За Waiting for device отвечает adb. У вас adb должен найти устройство. Посмотрите, устройство отображается или нет.
 попробуйте:

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }`

Comment: Да. Все устройства отображаются. Вообщем, я просто сделал откат проекта. Решения так и не нашел. Спасибо за помощь.